# Insert a variable value inside F# quotation

Tags: f#, quotations

so I have a function named evalExpr which accepts as argument a quotation <@ ... @> and it returns a value.
For example if I write

```
let v = evalExpr <@ 22 + 2 * 22 + 45 @>
```

then, v is equal to 111.

Now, I want to place inside the quotations a string variable instead of the expressions, but doing this, the variable is part of the quotation and so not defined.

How can I use variable values inside quotations in F#?

Comment: What is the problem? You can use outer variables inside quotations, as shown here, for example: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/21/composed-assertions-with-unquote

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to parse expression out of the string?

Comment: Or are you looking for something like this: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics/blob/master/src/Symbolics/Script.fsx#L143

Answer (score 3):

[Unquote](https://code.google.com/p/unquote/) features an operator `evalWith : Map<string,obj> -> Quotations.Expr<'a> -> 'a` that allows you to evaluate *synthetic* quotations with unbound variables using an environment map that provides the variable values.

First, open the `Swensen.Unquote` namespace to make the `evalWith` operator available.

```
open Swensen.Unquote;;
```

Next, construct a quotation which represents a variable `x` of type `int`:

```
let xvar : Quotations.Expr<int> = Quotations.Expr.Var(new Quotations.Var("x", typeof<int>)) |> Quotations.Expr.Cast;;
```

Next, construct a quotation with the `xvar` spliced in:

```
let q = <@ %xvar + 10 @>;;
```

Now you can evaluate your quotation `q` with the variable `x` provided like so:

```
evalWith (Map.ofList [("x", box 2)]) q;;
```

The answer is `12`!

Comment: In the code `valWith (Map.ofList [("x", box 2)]) q` box, requires an integer value. In my example, I took a more complex expression. For this reason, the user would be able to insert in input just a number, and it would process the calculate. If I insert a string (like "2 + 2 * 2"), it doesn't work and so I don't solve the problem. Anyway why do you put double ;;? F# doesn't even require them.

Comment: Quotations can be constructed with a literal string or synthetically, but there is no out-of-the-box facility converting a dynamic string of F# code into a quotation. But you could write such a routine your self: i.e. a function `parse : string -> Quotations.Expr` which parses a string into an AST and builds a quotation from that. Obviously you wouldn't write a parser for the entire F# language, but for a small arithmetic language.

Comment: I used `;;` because I was working in FSI. You can of course omit those in an F# source file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Unquote 3.1.0 and newer.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis yes, there was a breaking change required a while back, the new signature is `val inline evalWith : Map<Var,obj> -> Quotations.Expr<'a> -> 'a` ... from this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/575

Comment: @StephenSwensen, I see. Thank you! And yes, Unquote is such a great library.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what exactly you're asking for, but maybe something like this would help?

```
type Vars<'a> private () =
    static let dict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Quotations.Var>()
    static member Var(nm) = 
        match dict.TryGetValue nm with
        | true, v -> v
        | _ -> 
            let v = Quotations.Var(nm, typeof<'a>)
            dict.[nm] <- v
            v

[<GeneralizableValue>]
let x<'a> : Quotations.Expr<'a> = Quotations.Expr.Var(Vars<'a>.Var "x") |> Quotations.Expr.Cast

[<GeneralizableValue>]
let y<'a> : Quotations.Expr<'a> = Quotations.Expr.Var(Vars<'a>.Var "y") |> Quotations.Expr.Cast


let q1 = <@ %x + %y * (1 + %x) @>

let q2 = <@ "test" + %x @>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get an expression in input and solve it with that function. For this reason, the expression in input must be a string, taken by Console.ReadLine(). For example if I insert in input "22 + 2 * 22 + 45", it should return 111 like it does with the normal quotation. Anyway I'm not able to do it with this code, the result returned is Unsupported expression. Where do x and y take value from? How can I give a value taken by input?